# Help determining proper Identity Range sizes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, identity-column, merge-replication

I have a Merge Replication with ~200 subscribers.  I am trying to determine what would be appropriate Identity Range Sizes on some of the tables.  You see I inherited a DB structure that was not designed for Replication therefore all table PK's are int IDENTITY's.  Unfortunately some of these tables were built WITHOUT any tracking fields so I have no idea when they were inserted so I am having trouble formulating an estimate for the size of Subscriber Range needed.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be too late in your case, but in situations like this I prefer to avoid worrying about ranges all together. Instead, I'll set the identity seed value uniquely on each database and increment by an appropriate power of 10.

For example, if I had less than 10 subscribers, I'd use:

```
Database 1: IDENTITY(1,10) - produces 1, 11, 21, ...
Database 2: IDENTITY(2,10) - produces 2, 12, 22, ...
Database 3: IDENTITY(3,10) - produces 3, 13, 23, ...
...
```

Comment: That probably wouldn't work so well for ~200 subscribers though?

Comment: Honestly never tried it with that many, but in theory, the technique would be the same. The obvious drawback is that your IDs will grow pretty quickly as you'd be incrementing by 1000.